# List Libraries with the same name. Is this a bug?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list

I've just come across the following and was wondering if this might be a bug.

When using the SharePoint UI it does not allow you to create a list with the same name. However, if I create the library with a unique name and then go back and update it with the name of a list that already exists in the site it allows me to apply the change. The reason I ask this is when using CSOM it has the following method which only returns a single value :

```
web.Lists.GetByTitle("Test");
```

[image: Multiple lists with same name]

Should you be able to do this? If you are why does it not allow you do this when creating a library?

I've tested the following on SharePoint 2010 and it does not allow lists with the same name. Will test the other versions today.

Comment: Yes you can create duplicates like you experienced. But like you experienced you can't get at them byTitle anymore, only by GUID or other iteration method. Bug? no.. Used it when deploying multiple languages in one site, letting the user delete (Add-In UI) what they did't want.

Comment: Maybe it won't pose any problems but can you risk it? What will happen in an upgrade? My rule of a thumb is to NEVER create a calendar named calendar - name it calendar1. Side effects could be unpredicted and they may show years after

Answer (score 1):

In my last experience at work, our customer somehow created two Calendar library with the same name 'Calendar', one for the team and the other for the group. This caused SP service (.svc) end-point crash. And after rename one list library to a different name, it solve the crashing issue.

Comment: luckily it doesn't appear to crash. Just gets the first value. The only thing I can see beside the guid to distinguish it is the view url